# Typesafe: how to define different configuration for various environments?

Tags: configuration, settings, environment, typesafe

I would like to define separate settings for different environments:

```html
env {
  qa {
    fass_url = "https://..."

    client_id = "1111"
  }
  uat {
    fass_url = "https://www...."

    client_id = "2222"
    }
}
```

How to load those settings for different environment? The following code does not work:

```
private[this] val config = ConfigFactory.load()

val env_sett = "qa"

val env = if (env_sett == "qa") "env_qa"
            else if (env_sett == "uat") "env_uat"
            else "env_test_uat"
```